# Are open array parameters, classes and strings passed by reference?

Tags: delphi

I have read on SO that open array parameters are passed by reference automatically. Is this the same thing for classes and strings or I have to use the var?

I refer to the fact that I want to pass to a function (or procedure) a parameter by reference. Like in C++ I always pass std::string& for example, it is explicit otherwise I pass a copy

Comment: I removed question 1 from your original post. It is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507310/whats-the-difference-between-var-and-out-parameters And it is strictly one question at a time here. Your other question is fine I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statement about open arrays is not correct. There are three forms of open array parameter:

```
procedure ByValue(arr: array of Integer);
procedure ConstParam(const arr: array of Integer);
procedure VarParam(var arr: array of Integer);
```

The final two forms, var and const, pass a reference to the array. However, the first, passing by value, passes a copy. If you want to avoid making a copy, then you should use either a var or const parameter. Choose between these depending on whether or not you wish the caller's array to be modified.

As for classes and strings, these types are reference types. Since they are already references, when you pass one to a procedure, you are passing the reference.

Let's look at the various possibilities for classes:

```
procedure ByValue(obj: TObject);
procedure ConstParam(const obj: TObject);
procedure VarParam(var obj: TObject);
procedure OutParam(out obj: TObject);
```

For `ByValue` and `ConstParam`, the reference is passed directly. The difference between the two is that in the implementation of `ConstParam`, the reference cannot be modified. It can in `ByValue`. The caller cannot see that modification. Of course, you can always call methods on `obj` that modify the state of the object. In practice there's little point in using `const` for a reference type.

For `VarParam` and `OutParam`, the address of the reference is passed. Thus the procedure receives a pointer to a pointer to the object. All of the pointer handling is hidden from you. But this is what allows you to modify the reference and have the caller see that modification.

Strings are also reference types, and so are handled similarly.

Comment: Ok now I have understood thank you, the pointer to a pointer thing is what I needed to be confirmed. Just last thing: records instead are NOT references like classes correct?

Comment: Classes are on the heap, records on the stack! So records are not reference types like classes. Delphi makes what you do in C++ using new

Comment: Records are value types, not reference types. But it is incorrect to state that they live on the stack. If dynamically allocated or contained inside classes, they are on the heap.